# Append text to the end of data

Tags: jquery

I have a script that uses dataTables to display data. In the "callback" section I have the following code.

When the "if statement is true I need to append text "OFFLINE" to the end of the data, example: Some text - OFFLINE.

I know the code below is wrong but how can this be done

```
rowCallback: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {

  if(data.MessageCount == 2 ) {
    $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('DeviceOffline HeaderStatusWayfinderWhiteTextBlink), .append('Offline')';
    $(row).attr('title', 'Display screen offline');

  $(row).find('td:eq(0)').on('click', function () {
    $('#open_offline_help').modal('show');
  });
  }

  else if(data.DisplayMainBoard == 0 && data.RecordCount >= 1){
    $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('RoomStatusTableOverrideOn') ;
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have a reproducible example of your code syntax error?

Comment: Hi, this is the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at
  $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('DeviceOffline HeaderStatusWayfinderWhiteTextBlink), .append('Offline')';

Comment: edit this line to ` $(row).find('td:eq(0)').addClass('DeviceOffline HeaderStatusWayfinderWhiteTextBlink').append('Offline')`

Comment: @Tachibana Shin Perfect, many thanks. I can see where I was wrong. Thanks

Comment: So, is there still an issue or was it due to the erroneous comma/quote?